# Error after converting prioject to VB.NET (From C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters, automapper

I want to converter this C# to VB.NET

```
internal static void CreateMap(AutoMapperService autoMapperService)
    {
        Player.CreateMap(autoMapperService);
        RawStats.CreateMap(autoMapperService);

        autoMapperService.CreateMap<string, GameTypeEnum>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => GameTypeConsts.GameTypes
                .First(x => x.Value == s).Key);

        autoMapperService.CreateMap<string, GameModeEnum>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => GameModeConsts.GameModes
                .First(x => x.Value == s).Key);

        autoMapperService.CreateMap<string, GameSubTypeEnum>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => GameSubTypeConsts.GameSubTypes
                .First(x => x.Value == s).Key);

        CreateMap<Game>(autoMapperService);
        CreateMap<IGame>(autoMapperService).As<Game>();

        autoMapperService.CreateMap<RecentGamesDto, IEnumerable<IGame>>()
            .ConvertUsing(x => x.Games.Select(autoMapperService.Map<GameDto, IGame>));
    }
```

VB.NET:

```
 Friend Shared Sub CreateMap(autoMapperService As AutoMapperService)
        Player.CreateMap(autoMapperService)
        RawStats.CreateMap(autoMapperService)

        autoMapperService.CreateMap(Of String, GameTypeEnum).ConvertUsing(Function(s) GameTypeConsts.GameTypes.First(Function(x) x.Value = s).Key)

        autoMapperService.CreateMap(Of String, GameModeEnum).ConvertUsing(Function(s) GameModeConsts.GameModes.First(Function(x) x.Value = s).Key)

        autoMapperService.CreateMap(Of String, GameSubTypeEnum).ConvertUsing(Function(s) GameSubTypeConsts.GameSubTypes.First(Function(x) x.Value = s).Key)

        CreateMap(Of Game)(autoMapperService)
        CreateMap(Of IGame)(autoMapperService).[As](Of Game)()

        autoMapperService.CreateMap(Of RecentGamesDto, IEnumerable(Of IGame))().ConvertUsing(Function(x) x.Games.Select(autoMapperService.Map(Of GameDto, IGame)))
    End Sub
```

I and up getting an exception at the last VB.NET Codeline:
[image]
Telling me that I am missing the item property

Thats the original project:
https://github.com/XeeX/LeagueOfLegendsAPI
This is the function where I am missing the item property:
https://github.com/XeeX/LeagueOfLegendsAPI/blob/master/PortableLeagueApi.Core/Services/AutoMapperService.cs

Can someone give me a hint what am I missing?

Regards

Comment: Don't do it. Don't convert to VB.NET and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure (my VB.NET skills are rusty), but I think the problem is how you're trying to pass the `Map` method as a parameter to `Select` method. Try using [`AddressOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx):

```vb
autoMapperService.CreateMap(Of RecentGamesDto, IEnumerable(Of IGame))().ConvertUsing(Function(x) x.Games.Select(AddressOf autoMapperService.Map(Of GameDto, IGame)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for my problem.